# What does it mean by extending a commutative diagram in Snake Lemma?

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

The following is taken from $\textit{Module Theory An Approach to Linear Algebra}$ By: T.S.Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise 4.5}$ $\textbf{[The snake diagram]}$  Suppose that the diagram of $R-$modules and $R-$morphisms

[image] (1)

is commutative and has exact rows.  Show that this diagram can be extended to a diagram

[image] (2)

which is also commutative and has exact rows and columns. Show also that there isa  'connecting $R-$morphism' $d:\text{Ker }\gamma\to A'/\text{im }\alpha$ such that

$\text{ker }\alpha\xrightarrow{u_1}\text{ker }\beta\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }\gamma\xrightarrow{d}A'/\text{Im }\alpha\xrightarrow{u_2}B'/\text{Im }\beta\xrightarrow{v_2}C'/\text{Im }\gamma$

is exact.

[$\textit{Hint.}$ To construct $d:$ given $x\in\text{Ker }\gamma$ let $y\in B$ be such that $v(y)=k(x).$  Show that $\beta(y)\in \text{ker }v'$ so that there exists a unique $a'\in A'$ such that $u'(a')=\beta(y).$  Show that the prescription $d(x)=p(a')$ is well defined (i.e., independent of $\gamma$) and does the trick.]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I would like to know for the exercise above, what does it when it ask the reader to "Show that this diagram can be extended to a diagram"?  Does it mean that I can build another commutative diagram from (1) so that the following exact sequence

$\text{ker }\alpha\xrightarrow{u_1}\text{ker }\beta\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }\gamma$

is exact?  Similarly, I can build another bottom commutative diagram connecting (1) to show the following exact sequence

$A'/\text{Im }\alpha\xrightarrow{u_2}B'/\text{Im }\beta\xrightarrow{v_2}C'/\text{Im }\gamma$

is exact?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The author says *Show that this diagram can be extended to a diagram [picture] which is also commutative and has exact rows and columns.* I would take that at face value. Part one of the exercise to show that there is such a diagram with exact rows and columns.  Part two is about the existence of a homomorphism connecting the freshly constructed new exact rows. Observe that those two new rows were initially claime to only be exact at the middle. That is, at $\mathrm{ker}\beta$ and at $B'/\mathrm{Im}\beta$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen for part one where it asks I have to show there is such a diagram with exact rows and columns, I have to show the existence of $\text{ker }(\alpha) \xrightarrow{u_1} \text{ker }(\beta)\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }(\gamma)$ and $\text{coker }(\alpha) \xrightarrow{u_2} \text{coker }(\beta)\xrightarrow{v_2}\text{coker }(\gamma),$ as homomorphisms and then show that both are exact?  I know how to do those steps.  I am just not sure if that is what the question is asking for part one.